# Meson Build System -- Cross Compiling

Tags: build-system, meson-build

This is my first time using the Meson build system and I'm doing a cross compilation of a simple project; it should be straight forward but I'm getting the following error and I hope you can provide some help with it.

> meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unable to detect linker for compiler ".\tools\gcc_compiler\bin\ppc-freevle-eabi-gcc -Wl,--version -c -mcpu=e200z4 -mvle -meabi -msdata=none -mregnames -O2 -gdwarf-2 -fomit-frame-pointer -falign-functions=16 -fno-gcse -std=gnu99"

This is what my cross_file.build looks like:

```
[constants]
compiler_path = '.\tools\gcc_compiler\bin\'
arch = 'ppc-freevle-eabi' 

[binaries]
c       = compiler_path + arch + '-gcc'
cpp     = compiler_path + arch + '-cpp'
ld      = compiler_path + arch + '-ld'
ar      = compiler_path + arch + '-ar'
as      = compiler_path + arch + '-as'
size    = compiler_path + arch + '-size'
objdump = compiler_path + arch + '-objdump'
objcopy = compiler_path + arch + '-objcopy'
strip   = compiler_path + arch + '-strip'
gdb     = compiler_path + arch + '-gdb'

[built-in options]
c_args      = [
                '-c',
                '-mcpu=e200z4',
                '-mvle',
                '-meabi',
                '-msdata=none',
                '-mregnames',
                '-O2',
                '-gdwarf-2',
                '-fomit-frame-pointer',
                '-falign-functions=16',
                '-fno-gcse',
                '-std=gnu99'
               ]

c_link_args = [
               '-mcpu=e200z4',
               '-mvle',
               '-meabi',
               '-msdata=none',
               '-mregnames',
               '-O2',
               '-gdwarf-2',
               '-fomit-frame-pointer',
               '-falign-functions=16',
               '-fno-gcse',
               '-std=gnu99',
               '-ffunction-sections',
               '-fdata-sections',
               '-fno-common',
               '-nostartfiles',
               '-Wl,-Map=build/out.map',
               '--cref,--no-warn-mismatch,--library-path=,--gc-sections,-lm,-lc,-z,max-page-size=16384,--script=application.ld -o build/out.elf'
              ]

[host_machine]
system = 'windows'
cpu_family = 'x86'
cpu = 'i686'
endian = 'little'
```

If I execute the same command in the command line, I don't get any error, but for some reason meson does not like, any idea?

Thanks!